# Why does vulkan report a single device in a system with an integrated graphics card and a GPU?

Tags: c++, graphics, gpu, hardware, vulkan

In C++ I am checking the number of available devices like this:

```
uint32_t deviceCount = 0;
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, nullptr);

cout << deviceCount << endl;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(device, &deviceProperties);
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(device, &deviceFeatures);

cout << deviceProperties.deviceName << endl;
```

This is printing out `1 Geforce GTX 1070`.

My system has a GTX 1070 and a 4th generation intel 5 processor with integrated graphics. Which to my understanding, should be good enough for Vulkan.

So why is my program only picking up the GTX 1070? Shouldn't it also be able to find the integrated graphics card?

Edit:

The exact model as per cpuinfo is: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz`

Edit 2:

My OS is Arch linux

Comment: It depends in the *specific* `Core i5` model, no? The Intel "i5" is a wide range of CPUs/revisions - ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API) for the versions supported. Note that *only* i5-6000+ series of chips are supported (FSVO) in all Vulkan environments..

Comment: (So, if 4th gen = 4000-series then then it's too old and not supported, even if the integrated graphics might 'computationally' be capable of supporting such.)

Comment: Seems that's the answer then

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: To my knowledge, only 6+ gen CPU supported on windows, and 3+ gen supported on Linuxes ATM.

Comment: I am on linux. Arch linux specifically

Comment: @krOoze do you  have a source for that?  I thought that it was only 6+ gen period.

Comment: @opa Actually, the link in first comment says so. I have 3rd gen at hand; it works in linux distro via the Mesa driver.

Comment: @krOoze looks like you're correct, so it isn't Intel officially supporting it?

Comment: @Makogan What version of Mesa do you have? it looks like support is conditional on the version of Mesa as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default for desktops if you have dedicated GPU, integrated GPU is disabled in bios and will not show as a device in system.

Each bios vendor calls it differently, but try to look for "IGP ENABLE" or "Multi-monitor support".